# How does the C++ function `modf` work internally?

Tags: c++

I get what it does, but I'd like to know what the function is doing internally to separate out the floating point number.  I can think of a really hacky way to do it using an integer cast, but I'm really hoping that it's a more elegant solution than that...Does it access the bits directly and convert?

Comment: Have you seen: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/modf?  Also, you can look at the source for libstdc++ and libc++ to see how it is implemented.

Comment: @NathanOliver: I did see the reference, but it mentions that the function is implemented *as though* it were done the way they showed, plus the question just gets kicked down the line: how does the rounding work.  I did not, however, look at the source, so I suppose I should go do that.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm sure when you look at the code you'll see that it manipulates the bits directly.

Comment: Also, to add, while looking at the code will help you understand what kind of tricks could be used to implement such a function, how it is actually implemented might be different in different implementations of the library, which might or might not perform better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking around, I found an implementation [source](http://www.netlib.org/fdlibm/s_modf.c),

```
#ifdef __STDC__
    double modf(double x, double *iptr)
#else
    double modf(x, iptr)
    double x,*iptr;
#endif
{
    int i0,i1,j0;
    unsigned i;
    i0 =  __HI(x);      /* high x */
    i1 =  __LO(x);      /* low  x */
    j0 = ((i0>>20)&0x7ff)-0x3ff;    /* exponent of x */
    if(j0<20) {         /* integer part in high x */
        if(j0<0) {          /* |x|<1 */
        __HIp(iptr) = i0&0x80000000;
        __LOp(iptr) = 0;        /* *iptr = +-0 */
        return x;
        } else {
        i = (0x000fffff)>>j0;
        if(((i0&i)|i1)==0) {        /* x is integral */
            *iptr = x;
            __HI(x) &= 0x80000000;
            __LO(x)  = 0;   /* return +-0 */
            return x;
        } else {
            __HIp(iptr) = i0&(~i);
            __LOp(iptr) = 0;
            return x - *iptr;
        }
        }
    } else if (j0>51) {     /* no fraction part */
        *iptr = x*one;
        __HI(x) &= 0x80000000;
        __LO(x)  = 0;   /* return +-0 */
        return x;
    } else {            /* fraction part in low x */
        i = ((unsigned)(0xffffffff))>>(j0-20);
        if((i1&i)==0) {         /* x is integral */
        *iptr = x;
        __HI(x) &= 0x80000000;
        __LO(x)  = 0;   /* return +-0 */
        return x;
        } else {
        __HIp(iptr) = i0;
        __LOp(iptr) = i1&(~i);
        return x - *iptr;
        }
    }
}
```

but can not say for certain whether or not this is the one currently used. As you suspected, it is not identical to the explanation given at cppreference. It directly manipulates the bits within the floating point number. I did not work through the details of this optimized code but do not suspect anything particularly deep.